# Cmd line window not closing after batch file completes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2003

From what I understand, the command line should close automatically after a batch script finishes.
Mine is not closing - which means that it is getting caught up on some task.
I'm not sure what's wrong though - because apart from not closing - the script is working fine!

I'm on a windows 2003 server, this is the batch:

```
TASKKILL /IM rfbase.exe /F 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000
cd /D C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop
CALL service_restart.bat
cd /D E:\Program Files\Accellos\Accellos One Warehouse\RbHandHeld
RFBASE.EXE
EXIT 0
```

Comment: How do you start your batch ? try this : `cmd.exe /C c:\path\to\your_batch.bat`

Comment: This is funny, most people complain of the opposite problem.

Comment: Well - I think its causing a problem with my task scheduler - the task wont run consecutively - so I assumed it might not be able to open the prompt if its already open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is your script is waiting for RFBASE.EXE to terminate - though I can't be sure. If this is the cause, then you should be able to fix the problem by invoking RFBASE via START:

```
TASKKILL /IM rfbase.exe /F 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000
cd /D C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop
CALL service_restart.bat
cd /D E:\Program Files\Accellos\Accellos One Warehouse\RbHandHeld
start RFBASE.EXE
EXIT 0
```

Comment: This seems likely to be the answer - the TASKKILL at the start implies that RFBASE is a long running program.

Answer (score 0):

Using the CALL command gives control to the "service_restart.bat" file. Control won't return to the CALLing batch file until the called batch file completes or the EXIT command is encountered in the called batch.